# ggplot2: geom_text() with facet_grid()?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I just want to add annotation to each panel of figures generated by ggplot2; just simple labels like (a), (b), (c), etc. in each corner. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a picture as an example, you could post?

Comment: Sorry, I need to figure out how to post pictures...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/RL8M7Ut5EpU you can use the following:

```
library(ggplot2) 
x <-runif(9, 0, 125) 
data <- as.data.frame(x) 
data$y <- runif(9, 0, 125) 
data$yy <- factor(c("a","b","c")) 

ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point(shape = 2) + 
    facet_grid(~yy) + 
    geom_text(aes(x, y, label=lab),
        data=data.frame(x=60, y=Inf, lab=c("this","is","the way"),
             yy=letters[1:3]), vjust=1)
```

which should give you this:

[image]

Comment: +1, but could you provide a little more context to how this works? Right now it is just a piece of code and a picture.

Comment: Sure. The base `ggplot` call has the data frame with the actual plot data for the `geom_point` `facet_grid` facets. The key is to setup a new data frame for the `geom_text` (created on the fly in the code snippet, but you could create it outside the `ggplot` block and just reference the data frame) and match the number of label elements to the number of facets. You can use multiple calls to `geom_text` to place multiple, different labels across the facets. They'll be referenced in order, so be mindful of that.

Comment: If you want multiple labels to be drawn there is no need to call geom_text multiple times, just add rows to your data.frame with the appropriate text and facet_grid variables.

Comment: Ah, I'd seen it but wasn't working because I had the hjust wrong. Thanks. But do you knoww the conditions under which `Inf` works? Mine just says, `Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 'from' must be of length 1`.

Comment: having multiple `geom_text`'s helps (IMO) if you want easier to read code for a general audience and makes it easier to tweak formatting on different labels (which I pbly errantly assumed was the case)

Comment: @hrbrmstr -- Thanks for this great answer. I was wondering if you could provide the recipe for when x is a discrete variable?

Answer (score 8):

Basically, you create a `data.frame` with the text which contains a column with the text, and a column with the variables you use for `facet_grid`. You can then simply add a `geom_text` with that `data.frame`. See the documentation of `geom_text` for more details on text placement and such.

Answer (score 1):

I found this approach that maybe could be a solution for the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499601/13997761