# Label individual panels in a multi-panel ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, panel

I'm interested in trying to create simple corner labels for a multipanel figure I am preparing in ggplot. [This is similar to this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867263/ggplot2-geom-text-with-facet-grid), but the answers only explained how to include a label at the top of the plot, not produce a corner label in the format required by many journals. I hope to replicate something similar to the `plotrix` function `corner.label()` in `ggplot2`.

Here is an example using `plottrix` of what I would like to recreate in `ggplot2`.

```
require(plotrix)

foo1<-rnorm(50,25,5)
foo2<-rpois(50,25)
foo3<-rbinom(50,25,0.5)
foo4<-rnbinom(50,25,0.5)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
hist(foo1)
corner.label(label='a',figcorner=T)
hist(foo2)
corner.label(label='b',figcorner=T)
hist(foo3)
corner.label(label='c',figcorner=T)
hist(foo4)
corner.label(label='d',figcorner=T)
```

This produces the following:

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the labeling should look like? Do you just need the facet labels all shoved to the left? Or do you need to remove the facet label ribbons entirely?

Comment: I just need to justify the labels to the upper-left-hand corner of each panel. I'm not sure what you mean by removing the facet label ribbons..

Comment: Ok, then see `?theme` and set the hjust for `strip.text`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and came up with the following solution, which is a bit different:

## loading r packages

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
```

## example data

```
a <- 1:20
b <- sample(a, 20)
c <- sample(b, 20)
d <- sample(c, 20)
```

## create a data frame

```
mydata   <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)
```

## create example plots

```
myplot1  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point()
myplot2  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=b, y=c)) + geom_point()
myplot3  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=c, y=d)) + geom_point()
myplot4  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=d, y=a)) + geom_point()
```

## set corner labels

```
myplot1 <- arrangeGrob(myplot1, top = textGrob("A", x = unit(0, "npc")
         , y   = unit(1, "npc"), just=c("left","top"),
         gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=18, fontfamily="Times Roman")))

myplot2 <- arrangeGrob(myplot2, top = textGrob("B", x = unit(0, "npc")
         , y = unit(1, "npc"), just=c("left","top"),
         gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=18, fontfamily="Times Roman")))

myplot3 <- arrangeGrob(myplot3, top = textGrob("C", x = unit(0, "npc")
        , y  = unit(1, "npc"), just=c("left","top"),
        gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=18, fontfamily="Times Roman")))

myplot4 <- arrangeGrob(myplot4, top = textGrob("D", x = unit(0, "npc")
        , y = unit(1, "npc"), just=c("left","top"),
        gp=gpar(col="black",    fontsize=18, fontfamily="Times Roman")))
```

## plotting all plots on one page

```
grid.arrange(myplot1, myplot2, myplot3, myplot4, ncol = 2)
```

[image: corner label]

Comment: This is great. This is much simpler and more generally applicable and easier to implement than the accepted solution IMO.  Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Two recent changes have made this a lot easier:

- The latest release of `ggplot2` has added the `tag` caption which can be used to label subplots.
- The package `patchwork` makes it really easy to plot multiple ggplot objects. https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork

This means that no altering of grobs is required. Adapting the reproducible example provided by Kev:

```
library(ggplot2)
# install.package("patchwork")
library(patchwork)

a <- 1:20
b <- sample(a, 20)
c <- sample(b, 20)
d <- sample(c, 20)
mydata   <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)

myplot1  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point() + labs(tag = "A")
myplot2  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=b, y=c)) + geom_point() + labs(tag = "B")
myplot3  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=c, y=d)) + geom_point() + labs(tag = "C")
myplot4  <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=d, y=a)) + geom_point() + labs(tag = "D")

myplot1 + myplot2 + myplot3 + myplot4
```

[image]

**Extension: Changing Style:**

If you want to change the labelling style, you can either set this individually for each plot or set a theme default. I would recommend the second approach. Add the following line before you build your plots to make the font **bold** and **blue**

```
ggplot2::theme_update(plot.tag = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "blue"))
```

For more information on customising the theme of ggplot2, see [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html).

Comment: Can you make the `tag` in bold, change size, etc.? How would that be done?

Comment: Good question: added more to the original answer to cover your point. Pretty much every component of ggplot2 can be customised by the `theme` argument.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find documentation, but it seems not a lot of people use it!

Answer (score 6):

An example:

```
d <- data.frame(x = runif(16),
                y = runif(16),
                grp = rep(letters[1:4],each = 4))

ggplot(d,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
facet_wrap(~grp) + 
geom_point() + 
theme(strip.text = element_text(hjust = -0.05),
      strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to have the labels outside the plot/axes region? Similar to the 'figcorner=T' option in corner.label()?

Comment: @Thraupidae You can set the `hjust` to be negative, but then b and d will drift into the other panels.

Comment: @Thraupidae See my edit. I think that's closer to what you're after. (And should explain why I asked about the facet ribbons.)

Comment: OK and to prevent the drifting into other panels I suppose you just have to mess with the spacing using plot.margin?

Comment: Ah, yes that looks very close to what I was hoping with the facet ribbons removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a custom labeller function.   This doesn't invovle any manipulations to the data. Currently it only works with 1-dimensional facets (facet_wrap).  I'm still working on how to increment along a 2-D grid...

1. Define the labeller function

   ```
   make_labelstring <- function(mypanels) {
     mylabels <- sapply(mypanels, 
                        function(x) {LETTERS[which(mypanels == x)]})

     return(mylabels)
   }

   label_panels <- ggplot2::as_labeller(make_labelstring)
   ```
2. Pass `label_panels` as the labeller to `facet_wrap`

   ```
   library(ggplot2)
   data("diamonds")

   # create a faceted plot
   ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = depth, y = price)) +
     geom_point() +
     facet_wrap(~cut, labeller = label_panels) +
     theme(strip.text = element_text(hjust = -0),
           strip.background = element_blank())
   ```