# ggplot: place image in corner of panel

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to find a way to insert an image into the corner of a ggplot panel, without specifying the coordinates manually each time.

In this instance, I'm attempting to place a graphic in the top right.

```
library(magick)
library(ggplot2)
library(datasets)

homer <- magick::image_read("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jonathan-rey/simpsons/128/Homer-Simpson-04-Happy-icon.png")


g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(
    title = "Count of Auto by Class",
    subtitle = "Text to Create More Space")

g + annotation_custom(rasterGrob(homer, interpolate = TRUE),
                      xmax = Inf, ymax = Inf) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

I have found some examples that come close to solving this:

[Inserting an image to ggplot outside the chart area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463691/inserting-an-image-to-ggplot-outside-the-chart-area)

[Corner Labels in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576381/corner-labels-in-ggplot2)

But neither quite get there. Specifying the exact location at which to place the image seems to require quite a bit of trial-and-error on each plot created, especially when x is categorical.

I would also like to maintain the size of my original image; the code I've used above seems to stretch it across the plot.

Thanks in advance...much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
library(grid)
a <- rasterGrob(homer, interpolate = TRUE, 
                width=unit(1,'cm'),
           x = unit(1,"npc"), y = unit(1,"npc"),
           hjust = 1, vjust=1)

g + annotation_custom(grob = a)
```

Comment: add some explanation

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually looking to place this outside the chart area, but that can be accomplished by adjusting hjust/vjust and setting `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`.

Now if I could just figure out how to keep my image from blurring ever so slightly...