# How to find the value corresponding to maximum value and label it in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, label, coordinates

I am dealing with tick data which contains price and volume(buy and sell).

I've tried codes from this post [How to label max value points in a faceted plot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351153/how-to-label-max-value-points-in-a-faceted-plot-in-r), yet still cannot solve it. I think what I wanna do is about x and y coordinates. e.g. the maximum volume (4622 ) happened at price 11360 and I would like to label 11360 at the point with maximum volume 4622.

Here is my codes :

```
ggplot(data=ts629sum) +  
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=BS,y=Price)) + 
  geom_label(filter(BS==max(BS)) + 
  aes(label(sprintf(%0.2f,y)), hjust=-0.5)
```

It would be appreciated if someone knows how to solve this problem.
[image]

Below is the dataset.

```
ts629sum <- structure(list(Price = 11315:11528, BS = c(236L, 340L, 266L, 
306L, 300L, 546L, 700L, 1106L, 1064L, 1312L, 1358L, 1126L, 876L, 
1382L, 1382L, 2290L, 2292L, 2282L, 2454L, 2710L, 3082L, 2252L, 
2214L, 2574L, 2498L, 3088L, 2644L, 2664L, 2558L, 2452L, 2508L, 
2122L, 2188L, 2152L, 1730L, 2222L, 1210L, 1074L, 1736L, 1750L, 
2340L, 2252L, 2004L, 2448L, 2590L, 4622L, 3428L, 3642L, 3628L, 
3960L, 4020L, 2690L, 2110L, 1974L, 1018L, 1182L, 796L, 788L, 
762L, 780L, 1442L, 1048L, 814L, 862L, 616L, 916L, 808L, 626L, 
552L, 506L, 588L, 888L, 1222L, 1942L, 1300L, 1856L, 1284L, 968L, 
932L, 1942L, 1320L, 1218L, 1514L, 1746L, 1886L, 3186L, 2540L, 
2194L, 2314L, 2166L, 3072L, 2344L, 2238L, 2568L, 2132L, 2806L, 
2606L, 2492L, 2610L, 2860L, 3754L, 2940L, 2754L, 3246L, 2912L, 
4018L, 3402L, 3534L, 3374L, 3028L, 3760L, 3820L, 3822L, 3890L, 
3296L, 4596L, 2780L, 2546L, 2958L, 2706L, 2990L, 2558L, 2518L, 
2462L, 2110L, 2818L, 2276L, 2184L, 1828L, 1436L, 1878L, 1468L, 
1464L, 1590L, 1580L, 2524L, 1586L, 1480L, 1702L, 1568L, 2490L, 
2074L, 1872L, 1872L, 1274L, 2000L, 1252L, 1194L, 1422L, 1422L, 
1630L, 1668L, 1798L, 2264L, 1806L, 2244L, 1480L, 2028L, 1616L, 
2074L, 2066L, 1798L, 1514L, 1440L, 1116L, 1308L, 780L, 816L, 
904L, 1162L, 1434L, 1042L, 1074L, 666L, 400L, 356L, 164L, 130L, 
110L, 48L, 48L, 54L, 36L, 34L, 28L, 106L, 32L, 56L, 64L, 54L, 
38L, 24L, 18L, 42L, 34L, 86L, 42L, 76L, 196L, 316L, 316L, 422L, 
418L, 358L, 300L, 348L, 378L, 238L, 214L, 178L, 248L, 168L, 76L, 
18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -214L))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `geom_label(data = filter(., BS==max(BS)), aes(label=BS))`. Change `label=BS` to `label=Price` (or whatever you wish) depending on what you want the label value to be.

Comment: Better than `==max` (which is a floating-point comparison, risky) is `data = ~ slice(., which.max(BS))`.

Comment: Your example is not real code, so some of this is made more difficult, wondering if some of your problems are because your real code contains these typos or something else. For starters, you need quotes around `%0.2f` and your `aes(label(...))` needs to be within `geom_label(...)`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the carelessness. I've attached the reproducible example with the input .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset the data in `geom_label` and keep only the row with max `BS`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=ts629sum, aes(x=BS,y=Price, label = Price)) +  
  geom_point() + 
  geom_label(data = ts629sum[which.max(ts629sum$BS), ], vjust = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Tbh, I was very close to the codes that you provided, yet failed to come up with the right ones. Thanks again!