# How can I add a geometric shape or an annotation to a single ggplot graphic in `facet_grid`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I made a faceted graph using `ggplot`, and then tried to use the function `annotate` to create a grey highlighted area in one specific panel of the plot only.

I tried to adapt the labeling method from this question, but I couldn't get it to work: 
[How to add annotation on each facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499396/how-to-add-annotation-on-each-facet)

Here is a reproducible example:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length))+
      geom_point(aes(y = Petal.Length))+
      facet_grid(Species~.)+
      annotate(geom = 'rect', xmin = 6, xmax = 6.5, ymin= 0, ymax= Inf,
               fill = 'grey20', alpha = 0.2)
```

output:

[image]

I want the  grey highlight to appear on only the `versicolor` facet, not every facet.

**EDIT**

As the user @user11362344 has proposed, i test his indication to use `geom_rect()`, and add to the code in the place of `annotate()` and *WORKED VERY WELL!*:

```
ggplot(data_2, aes(x = Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point(aes(y = Petal.Length))+
  facet_grid(Species~.)+
  geom_rect(data=data.frame(Species='versicolor'), inherit.aes=F, 
            xmin = 6, xmax = 6.5, ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, fill = 'grey20', alpha = 0.2)
```

output:

[image]

Thanks everyone for the help! And specially thanks for @user11362344!

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the observations, i edited my post with the help of another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  geom_rect(data=data.frame(Species='versicolor'), inherit.aes=FALSE,
            xmin = 6, xmax = 6.5, ymin= 0, ymax= Inf,
            fill = 'grey20', alpha = 0.2)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low-quality. Your answer is likely to be deleted if you don't edit it so as to add an explanation.