# Using facet tags and strip labels together in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-grid

I'd like to create a figure using `ggplot2`'s `facet_grid`, like below:

```r
# Load ggplot2 library for plotting
library(ggplot2)

# Plot dummy data
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) 
p <- p + geom_point() 
p <- p + facet_grid(gear ~ cyl)
print(p)
```

[image]

This is great, but since it's going in a journal article each panel also needs to be labelled with a, b, c, etc. The package `egg` has a great function for this called `tag_facet`, which is used as follows:

```r
# Load egg library for tagging
library(egg)
#> Warning: package 'egg' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Loading required package: gridExtra

# Same plot but with tags for each facet
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) 
p <- p + geom_point() 
p <- p + facet_grid(gear ~ cyl)
tag_facet(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

As required, I now how letter labels on each panel. But, as you can see, my strip labels have disappeared!

**My question**: How do I retain my strip labels, whilst also adding tags?

Comment: I haven't used it, but package [**stickylabeller**](https://github.com/rensa/stickylabeller#numbering-sequential-facets) might do what you want.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks, I'll check it out. I'm surprised that there isn't a function native to the tidyverse that does this, as it must be a fairly common problem...

Comment: This could be another approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499601/13997761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, I find a solution immediately after asking. The problem appears to be that `tag_facet` sets strip labels to `element_blank`, which can be fixed by calling `theme` *after* calling `tag_facet`.

```r
# Load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(egg)
#> Warning: package 'egg' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Loading required package: gridExtra

# Create plot
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) 
p <- p + geom_point() 
p <- p + facet_grid(gear ~ cyl)
p <- tag_facet(p)
p <- p + theme(strip.text = element_text())
print(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Maybe also `strip.background = element_rect()` if you want the background back.

Answer (score 9):

You can view the code for `tag_facet` [here](https://rdrr.io/github/baptiste/egg/src/R/tag_facet.r). As you can see, the function explicitly and deliberately removes the facet strips (see also the "value" in the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/github/baptiste/egg/man/tag_facet.html)). You can fix that by creating your own function, and just removing the `theme` call from the original code:

```
tag_facet2 <- function(p, open = "(", close = ")", tag_pool = letters, x = -Inf, y = Inf, 
    hjust = -0.5, vjust = 1.5, fontface = 2, family = "", ...) {

    gb <- ggplot_build(p)
    lay <- gb$layout$layout
    tags <- cbind(lay, label = paste0(open, tag_pool[lay$PANEL], close), x = x, y = y)
    p + geom_text(data = tags, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", label = "label"), ..., hjust = hjust, 
        vjust = vjust, fontface = fontface, family = family, inherit.aes = FALSE)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1), @iod. I noticed that in the code after asking. I think a simpler solution is just to set `strip.text = element_text()` to reintroduce the strip labels after adding the tags.

Comment: Not sure why that is simpler, but have it your way. I'll just note you also need to reset `strip.background`, to get the rectangles of the strips. Compare your output with mine in the two answers.

Comment: Perhaps simpler isn't the right word, but it's certainly briefer than redefining the tagging function.

Comment: That depends on how frequently you need to do it, I guess. Save the function as a file and source it whenever needed instead of calling on `egg`. But YMMV, of course.

Answer (score 5):

With {tagger} package, this can be made a little simpler. You can install `tagger` by using `devtools::install_github("eliocamp/tagger")`. After installing tagger, let's load it.

```
library(tagger)
library(ggplot2)

# Plot dummy data
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) 
p <- p + geom_point() 
p + facet_grid(gear ~ cyl) + tag_facets()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using only `geom_text()`  :

```
data_text <- data.frame(
  cyl   = c(4, 6, 8, 4, 6, 8, 4, 6, 8),
  gear  = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5)
  label = c('(a)', '(b)', '(c)', '(d)', '(e)', '(f)', '(g)', '(h)', '(i)')
)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
geom_point() +
facet_grid(gear ~ cyl) +
geom_text(data=data_text, aes(x=12, y=5, label=label), fontface='bold', size=4)
```

[image]

Comment: You can add `check_overlap = TRUE` to `geom_text` to make them look better