# export tag_facet to a .tif

Tags: r, ggplot2, egg

The following post: [facet_tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064042/using-facet-tags-and-strip-labels-together-in-ggplot2) was extremely helpful.  However, I don't seem to be able to export the figure with the labels.  I tried using the ggsave function.  The figure appears but the labels are no longer visible.  I can export using Rstudio but I need a high resolution file for publication.  Any ideas on a way to export these figures?  Thanks.

Comment: When you say 'labels' do you mean the strip labels or the tags?

Comment: I meant the tags (thanks for your question).  I don't actually want the strip labels, I just need a letter to appear in each of the facets.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me to save the image as a `.tiff` ([same](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/protocols-formats/difference-between-tif-and-tiff/#:%7E:text=TIF%20vs%20TIFF&text=Well%2C%20to%20cut%20to%20the,limitations%20imposed%20by%20file%20systems.) as `.tif`) with a specified `dpi`.

```
library(egg)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) 
p <- p + geom_point() 
p <- p + facet_grid(gear ~ cyl)
p <- tag_facet(p)

ggsave('test.tiff', p, dpi = 500)
```