# assign multiple geom_text() to corresponding facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet-grid

I followed this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867263/ggplot2-geom-text-with-facet-grid), which did not solve my problem.

Let's say I have a very large dataframe, of which a sample may look like:

```
> df_test
    time                pT          model Obs Pred               auc            brier
1  3-yrs pT3, pT4a or pT4b          18LNY 0.5  0.7  60.7 [46.9;74.4] 22.5 [17.8;27.2]
2  3-yrs pT3, pT4a or pT4b          18LNY 0.3  0.2  60.7 [46.9;74.4] 22.5 [17.8;27.2]
3  3-yrs        pT1 or pT2 LNY continuous 0.2  0.2  66.4 [55.4;77.4] 15.0 [11.0;19.0]
4  5-yrs        pT1 or pT2 LNY continuous 0.6  0.5  73.2 [63.4;83.0] 17.3 [13.1;21.6]
```

I am comparing prediction of two models in `df_test$model` in two different cancer stages `df_test$pT` at three different timepoints in `df_test$time`. I am using a `facet_grid(pT ~ time)`, which prints what I expect.

[image]

Now, I want to add a `geom_text` that print `df_test$auc` for each `df$model`, i.e. two "auc readouts" in *each* grid, one for `df_test$model == "18LNY"` and one for `df_test$model == "LNY continuous"`.

As you can see in the sample above, line 1 and 2 prints the same auc (because it belongs to the same model at the same timepoint). So I have reduced the dataframe to:

```
label_test <- df_test %>% select(time, pT, model, auc) %>% distinct()

# and
> label_test
    time                pT          model               auc
1  3-yrs pT3, pT4a or pT4b          18LNY  60.7 [46.9;74.4]
2  3-yrs        pT1 or pT2 LNY continuous  66.4 [55.4;77.4]
3  5-yrs        pT1 or pT2 LNY continuous  73.2 [63.4;83.0]
4   1-yr pT3, pT4a or pT4b          18LNY  59.9 [44.6;75.1]
5  5-yrs        pT1 or pT2          18LNY  73.5 [63.7;83.4]
6  3-yrs        pT1 or pT2          18LNY  66.4 [55.3;77.5]
7   1-yr        pT1 or pT2 LNY continuous 89.7 [77.7;100.0]
8  3-yrs pT3, pT4a or pT4b LNY continuous  61.1 [47.3;74.9]
9   1-yr pT3, pT4a or pT4b LNY continuous  59.7 [44.6;74.7]
10 5-yrs pT3, pT4a or pT4b          18LNY  63.5 [48.7;78.4]
11 5-yrs pT3, pT4a or pT4b LNY continuous  63.5 [48.6;78.4]
```

I then tried

```
ggplot(df_test, aes(x = Pred, y = Obs, color = model)) + 
  facet_grid(time ~ pT) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(data = label_test,
            aes(x = 0, y = c(0.8, 0.9), label = auc), 
            size = 5, hjust = 0, show.legend = FALSE)
```

Which gives

> Error in `check_aesthetics()`: ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or
> the same as the data (11): y

How to solve?

Data

```
df_test <- structure(list(time = c("3-yrs", "3-yrs", "3-yrs", "5-yrs", "1-yr", 
"5-yrs", "1-yr", "3-yrs", "1-yr", "5-yrs", "1-yr", "3-yrs", "5-yrs", 
"1-yr", "3-yrs", "5-yrs", "3-yrs", "3-yrs", "5-yrs", "5-yrs", 
"3-yrs", "3-yrs", "3-yrs", "5-yrs", "3-yrs"), pT = c("pT3, pT4a or pT4b", 
"pT3, pT4a or pT4b", "pT1 or pT2", "pT1 or pT2", "pT3, pT4a or pT4b", 
"pT1 or pT2", "pT3, pT4a or pT4b", "pT1 or pT2", "pT1 or pT2", 
"pT1 or pT2", "pT1 or pT2", "pT3, pT4a or pT4b", "pT1 or pT2", 
"pT3, pT4a or pT4b", "pT3, pT4a or pT4b", "pT1 or pT2", "pT1 or pT2", 
"pT1 or pT2", "pT3, pT4a or pT4b", "pT3, pT4a or pT4b", "pT3, pT4a or pT4b", 
"pT3, pT4a or pT4b", "pT3, pT4a or pT4b", "pT1 or pT2", "pT1 or pT2"
), model = c("18LNY", "18LNY", "LNY continuous", "LNY continuous", 
"18LNY", "18LNY", "18LNY", "18LNY", "LNY continuous", "18LNY", 
"LNY continuous", "LNY continuous", "LNY continuous", "LNY continuous", 
"LNY continuous", "LNY continuous", "18LNY", "LNY continuous", 
"18LNY", "LNY continuous", "18LNY", "LNY continuous", "LNY continuous", 
"LNY continuous", "LNY continuous"), Obs = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 
0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6), Pred = c(0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 
0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0, 0.8), auc = c("60.7 [46.9;74.4]", 
"60.7 [46.9;74.4]", "66.4 [55.4;77.4]", "73.2 [63.4;83.0]", "59.9 [44.6;75.1]", 
"73.5 [63.7;83.4]", "59.9 [44.6;75.1]", "66.4 [55.3;77.5]", "89.7 [77.7;100.0]", 
"73.5 [63.7;83.4]", "89.7 [77.7;100.0]", "61.1 [47.3;74.9]", 
"73.2 [63.4;83.0]", "59.7 [44.6;74.7]", "61.1 [47.3;74.9]", "73.2 [63.4;83.0]", 
"66.4 [55.3;77.5]", "66.4 [55.4;77.4]", "63.5 [48.7;78.4]", "63.5 [48.6;78.4]", 
"60.7 [46.9;74.4]", "61.1 [47.3;74.9]", "61.1 [47.3;74.9]", "73.2 [63.4;83.0]", 
"66.4 [55.4;77.4]"), brier = c("22.5 [17.8;27.2]", "22.5 [17.8;27.2]", 
"15.0 [11.0;19.0]", "17.3 [13.1;21.6]", "13.2 [8.7;17.7]", "17.2 [12.9;21.4]", 
"13.2 [8.7;17.7]", "14.9 [10.9;18.9]", "4.5 [2.1;6.8]", "17.2 [12.9;21.4]", 
"4.5 [2.1;6.8]", "22.4 [17.8;27.1]", "17.3 [13.1;21.6]", "13.3 [8.8;17.7]", 
"22.4 [17.8;27.1]", "17.3 [13.1;21.6]", "14.9 [10.9;18.9]", "15.0 [11.0;19.0]", 
"24.0 [18.4;29.6]", "23.9 [18.3;29.4]", "22.5 [17.8;27.2]", "22.4 [17.8;27.1]", 
"22.4 [17.8;27.1]", "17.3 [13.1;21.6]", "15.0 [11.0;19.0]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to fix your issue would be to add the `y` position for the labels to your `labels_df` which could then be mapped on the `y` aes.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

label_test <- df_test %>% 
  select(time, pT, model, auc) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  group_by(time, pT) %>% 
  mutate(y = seq(.8, .9, length.out = n())) %>% 
  ungroup()

ggplot(df_test, aes(x = Pred, y = Obs, color = model)) + 
  facet_grid(time ~ pT) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(data = label_test,
            aes(x = 0, y = y, label = auc), 
            size = 5, hjust = 0, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]